# How to increment automatically asset ids in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have to increment asset id's automatically in hyperledger composer. what is the best option available for that?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your ID in your client program before you call a Transaction in Composer - this is because as part of the endorsement process on Fabric, you Transaction will be executed on Multiple peers and will get different results, and therefore never successfully complete.  (This is a problem of writing non-deterministic transactions.)

This is already answered in more detail in this [Q&A on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628303/auto-increment-field-in-composer/47634115)